# How to color project folder when he contains a modified file, in Atom?

Tags: git, treeview, atom-editor

Atom colors every modified files and folder in orange by default, which is nice.
But the project folders don't follow this behaviour. This seems strange to me, I would like them to be colored in orange like any other folder when they contain modified files (my previous editor did this, and it was useful).

I installed the most known git pluggin, but to no avail.

Does someone know how to do this please ?

Answer (score 0):

In atom editor, only the root folder get colors according to the files states.
Make sure to make the folder where you are working the root directory so that you can follow your files changes.